# angular array dynamic binding binds to all the element instead of 1

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a array object like below

```
let myArray=[
 { "id":"100",
  "child1":[
    {"id":"xx","Array":[]},
    {"id":"yy","Array":[]},
      {"id":"zz","Array":[]}
    ]
 },
 {  "id":"200",
  "child1":[
   {"id":"xx","Array":[]},
    {"id":"yy","Array":[]},
      {"id":"zz","Array":[]}
    ]
 }
  ]
```

and i have angular template like bellow

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of myArray">
    Id:{{obj.id}}
 <div *ngFor="let objChild of obj.Child1">
    Id:{{objChild.id}}
    Array:{{objChild.Array}}    
    AddElementtoArray:<button (click)="add(objChild.Array)">add</button>    
   </div>
 </div>
```

and method to handle in angular component like the below

```
add(oArray)
{
oArray.push('xxx');
}
```

and if click the add button for the id 1 the values are added for both id 1 and 2 's child array, i tried other possibility like getting the index and filter it in code and try to add value for particular object child but it append for both the object 1 and 2, kindly let me how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this by sending both index the parent and the child, that will help you to get the specific element

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of myArray; let parentIdx = index;">
   Id:{{obj.id}}
 <div *ngFor="let objChild of obj.Child1; let childIdx = index;">
   Id:{{objChild.id}}
   Array:{{objChild.Array}}    
   AddElementtoArray:<button (click)="add(parentIdx, childIdx 
   )">add</button>    
 </div>
</div>
```

function

```
add(parentidx, childidx) {
  this.myArray[parentidx].Child1[childidx].Array.push('xxx');
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the replay i tried this too but still it is binding to all the object of the array

Comment: i have used a another angular variable to generate the child,i didn't make deep copy that is the problem